# $711.7$ base $10$ to base $2$

Tags: numerical-methods

I am attempting to solve the following two questions. The first question I believe I have done the whole number calculation correctly but I am confused how to do the decimal portion. The second question I am not sure about.

$1)$ Convert $711.7$ in base $10$ to base $2$

My solution.

Looking at the whole number to the left of the decimal $711$

$$(711)_{10} = 2^9 + 2^7 + 2^6 +2^2 + 2^0 \\ =1\cdot2^9 + 0\cdot 2^8 + 1\cdot 2^7 + 1 \cdot2^6 + 0\cdot 2^5 + 0\cdot 2^4 + 0\cdot 2^3 + 1 \cdot 2^2 + 0\cdot 2^2 + 1\cdot 2^0 \\= (1011000101)_2$$

Looking at the decimal part:

$$(0.7)_{10} = 2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-4} + 2^{-7}+...$$

This is getting closer to $0.7$ but it doesn't seem to ever actually equal it. So I how do I determine this? How do I show that it is repeating ?

My other question is can this answered be stored exactly on a computer?

Comment: 0.7 does not translate to an even binary fraction. It's a repeating one, as you've found. So no, it won't fit into 53 or any other finite number of bits of precision.

Comment: how do I show that it is repeating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting from base $10$ to base $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2920501/converting-from-base-10-to-base-2)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork how is this repeating?

Comment: A fraction has a finite radix representation in a particular base if it is a factor of some power of the base.  In this case, we have $7/10$; it will have finite representations in any base that's a multiple of 10, and it will not have such a thing in base 2.  The only other option for fractions is repeating digits; in this case, it's $0.1\overline{0110}$.

Comment: @DanUznanski how is it $0.10110$ repeating? could you show this?

Comment: This is the same question but with a different real number (5.1).  If you submitted the same question with 294.6 instead of 711.7, would that be a "different" question?

Comment: no but I am just trying to understand how I can show it is repeating, anyways thanks

Comment: @user123. You missed the overline in $0.1\overline{0110}$. It means the last 4 digits repeat forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a duplicate, i try to give the insight. It will not be short, but this is my everyday problem.

As a parallel, let us consider in **base ten** a periodic fraction. I will take $8/13$ which has the periodic decimal representation $0.\ 615384\ 615384\ 615384\ \dots=0.(615384)$ as i learned it in school. Now the reason for this is the fact that the first power of ten which is $1$ modulo $13$ is $10^6$, i.e. $999999/13=76923$ is the first $99\dots 9$ number divisible by $13$, the period comes from $999999/13\cdot 8 = 615384$ and the representation is shown by the long line
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac 8{13}
&=
\frac{615384}{999999}
\\
&=615384\cdot\frac 1{10^6}\cdot\frac 1{1-\frac 1{10^6}}
=615384\cdot\frac 1{10^6}\cdot\left(1+\frac 1{10^6}+\frac 1{10^{12}}+\dots\right)
\\
&=615384\cdot
0.\ 000001\ 000001\ 000001\ \dots
\\
&=0.\ 615384\ 615384\ 615384\ \dots\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(There is a little more dancing around when the denominator is not relatively prime to the basis ten.)
Sorry for this, but in our case we have a similar computation.

---

Same computational idea, an other basis.

$$
\begin{aligned}
0.7 &=\frac 7{10}=\frac 12\cdot \frac 75
=\frac 12\cdot\left(1+ \frac 25\right)
\\
&\text{ and the first $2$-power which is $1$ modulo $5$ is $16=2^4$, so...}
\\
&=\frac 12\cdot\left(1+ \frac 6{16-1}\right)
\\
&=\frac 12\cdot\left(1+ 6\cdot\frac 1{2^4}{1-\frac 1{2^4}}\right)
\\
&=\frac 12\cdot\left(1+ 6\cdot\left(
\frac 1{2^4} +
\frac 1{2^8} +
\frac 1{2^{12}} +
\dots
\right)\right)
\\
&=\frac 12\cdot\left(1+ 
\color{blue}{110}_{\color{red}{2}}\times
0.\ 0001\ 0001\ 0001\ \dots_{\color{red}{2}}
\right)
\\
&=\frac 12\cdot\left(1+ 
0.\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ \dots_{\color{red}{2}}
\right)
\\
&=\frac 12\cdot1.\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ \dots_{\color{red}{2}}
\\
&=0.1\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ 0\color{blue}{110}\ \dots_{\color{red}{2}}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Computer check:

```
sage: sum( [ 2.^-k for k in [1, 3,4, 7,8, 11,12, 15,16]] )
0.699996948242188
sage: sum( [ 2.^-k for k in [1, 3,4, 7,8, 11,12, 15,16, 19,20, 23,24, 27,28]] )
0.699999999254942
```

Note: The number can be stored exactly as a fraction, but not in binary representation.

Note: Add $711$ in binary for the final answer.